# Facebook PHP Api suddenly not working

Tags: php, facebook

```
<?php
//get token
$access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
$albumCover = $facebook->api("/". $album_id ."?fields=picture", "get");
//echo $albumCover['picture']['data']['url'];
//echo '<pre>';
//print_r($albumCover);
//echo '</pre>';
?>
<div class="fb-album<?php if ($counter % 5 == 0){echo ' no-right';}; ?>">
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
    <div style="width:160px; height:100px; overflow:hidden;">
        <img width="160px" src="<?php echo $albumCover['picture']['data']['url']; ?>" />
    </div>
    </a>
    <p><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title() ?></a></p>
    </div>
```

All of a sudden this doesnt work, and returns no error, could someone shed some light on this for me?

Thanks

UPDATE:

Found the answer, looks like I could not access the cover photo of each album with ?fields=picture anymore, I had to use ?fields=cover_photo and dig into that array, heres my solution, thanks for all your help STACK

```
<?php
                    //get token
                    $access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();

                    $albumCover = $facebook->api("/". $album_id ."?fields=cover_photo", "get");

                    //echo $albumCover['picture']['data']['url'];

                    $albumCover2 = $facebook->api("/". $albumCover['cover_photo'] ."?fields=picture", "get");

                    //echo '<pre>';
                    //print_r($albumCover2);
                    //echo '</pre>';


            ?>



            <div class="fb-album<?php if ($counter % 5 == 0){echo ' no-right';}; ?>">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
            <div style="width:160px; height:100px; overflow:hidden;">
                <img width="160px" src="<?php echo $albumCover2['picture']; ?>" />
            </div>
            </a>
            <p><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title() ?></a></p>
            </div>
```

I appologize for the formatting, its quite hard to make it look right in this editor

Answer (score 0):

Whenever Facebook API does not get data or does not work,

it logs error in PHP's error log. Check your PHP error log.

Comment: This is the error its throwing all of a sudden: 

[Wed Oct 02 11:49:44 2013] [warn] [client 208.82.90.66] mod_fcgid: stderr:  in /var/www/vhosts/dragonflynightclub.com/httpdocs/wp-content/themes/default-blank/page-photo-gallery.php on line 55, referer: http://dragonflynightclub.com/

Any Idea

Answer (score 0):

There was a breaking changes release [today](https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/); it's worth checking out the release notes to see how you might have been affected. At a guess, something to do with the privacy changes...

Comment: Wow this was what I was looking for, but I am not sure what part applies to me and how I can update my code

Answer (score 0):

You also need to use setAccessToken method after getAccessToken.

```
$access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
$facebook->setAccessToken($access_token);
```

Comment: could you give me an example of what that code would look like?

Answer (score 0):

As per the error message your have posted in the comment,

If the index active does not exist then you get notice error `mod_fcgid`. To avoid that you can do check if that index is set / exists.

Code:

```
if($blah['active']=="something"){foo();}
```

Should be:

Code:

```
if(isset($blah['active']) && $blah['active']=="something"){foo();}
```

Comment: I already know that its not returning anything, so i dont think i need to do this, just have to find out why the arrays suddenly arnt being returned